# Titanium: Labels and images won't show in Window

Tags: imageview, titanium, label

So I have to objects that I want to add to a Window in Titanium, but they will only show when I add them to something like a TableViewRow, not a Window. The two items I want to add are profileIcon and flowLabel. This is what I get in my header:

[image: Header]

```
var defaultFontSize = Ti.Platform.name === 'android' ? 16 : 14;

// Function to test if device is iOS 7 or later
function isiOS7Plus()
{
    // iOS-specific test
    if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'iPhone OS')
    {
        var version = Titanium.Platform.version.split(".");
        var major = parseInt(version[0],10);

        // Can only test this support on a 3.2+ device
        if (major >= 7)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var iOS7 = isiOS7Plus();
var theTop = iOS7 ? 59 : 0;

var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({top:theTop});

// Set the background color to non-black to see the status bar
// Or set the Window statusBarStyle property to a non-default value
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('#232a35');
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    // Remove the status bar
    // fullscreen: true
    // Moves the Window below the status bar
    top: theTop
});

var profileIcon = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: 'img/profile@2x.png',
    left:15,
    verticalAlign: 'center',
    width:12, height:14
});
win.add(profileIcon);

var flowLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color:'white',
    font:{fontFamily:'Lato-Bold', fontSize:defaultFontSize+2},
    text:'Flöde',
    textAlign: center,
    verticalAlign: center
});
win.add(flowLabel);
win.open();
```

This is the first app I'm developing btw and my previous skills are based on HTML and CSS, so if you've got any other tips to share on the way, please let me know.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

They're showing up behind your table view, that's why you're not seeing them. Neither have a  top or bottom set, and so will position themselves in the center of `window`.

The easiest solution is to add a view with the top's dimensions, then add the label and image to it.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
            fullscreen: true
});

var top = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0, height: 60
});
top.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: 'My Label', textAlign: 'center', color: '#000', left: 10 }));
top.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({ image: 'my/image.png', width: 40, height: 40, right: 10 }));
win.add(top);

win.add(Ti.UI.createTableView({
    top: 60
}));

win.open();
```